# Problems with Box Layout

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, scala, layout

I'm trying to use scala.swing package for my gui's. Before that, I was using plain GroupLayout (was writing it by hand :), but scala way seems better. I ran into some problems though - I like BoxLayout, but when I try to add several panes into it, and try to specify different horisontal alignments, I get something strange.

Here is the code:

```
new Frame {
  contents = new BoxPanel(Orientation.Vertical) {
    contents += new Button("A") {
      xLayoutAlignment = 1.0f
    }
    contents += new Button("B")
    size = (200, 200)
  }
  size = (200, 200)
  visible = true
  peer.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE)
}
```

At the very least, I expected to see button `B` to the left of the button `A`. Here is what I saw:

[image]

Java version of this code does exactly the same, so it is not scala.swing bug.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> and try to specify different horisontal alignments, I get something strange.

It's the way BoxLayout was designed to work.

See [Fixing Alignment Problems](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html#alignment) for a better explanation and a simple demo that allows you to play with alignments to better understand how they work.

Comment: I don't think that tutorial explains how BoxLayout was designed to work, and I challenge anyone to look at the source code and tell me what it is trying to do. The tutorial identifies the one case where the behavior is predictable, which is when every component has the same alignment.